# Question on Exchange of Operators - Bosons in Occupation Number Representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory

Say we have a state $|110\rangle$.  Let us then 'move' particles by destroying a particle at one site and creating it at another site in the state.  We will destroy a particle at momentum state 2 and create it at momentum state 3, i.e. $|101\rangle$.  Next we will destroy a particle at momentum state 1 and create it at momentum state 2, i.e. $|011\rangle$.  Finally we will destroy a particle at momentum state 3 and create it at momentum state 1, i.e. $|110\rangle$.  Hence we arrived at the same state we started with.

Given that, we have the algebraic expression for what just happened:

$\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1}\hat{a}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}\hat{a}_{1}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}\hat{a}_{2}|110\rangle$

Using the number operator I should be able to show that after these operations the two states are equal.  If I assume the particles are bosons and use the fact that two different particle states commute, i.e. $\left[\hat{a}_{i},\hat{a}_{j} \right] = 0$, I obtain the result

$\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1}\hat{a}_{1}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}\hat{a}_{2}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}\hat{a}_{3}|110\rangle$

After two swaps: 1) $\hat{a}_{3}$ with $\hat{a}_{1}$
2) $\hat{a}_{3}$ with $\hat{a}_{2}$

Apparently I am supposed to end up with

$\hat{a}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1}\hat{a}_{1}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}\hat{a}_{2}|110\rangle$

I do not see just from swapping how to get the above result as I keep obtaining $\hat{a}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}$ in reverse no matter what two swaps I make.  Could anyone offer any insight into what I am doing wrong or what I wrongly assumed?

Comment: The purpose of the above is me trying to test if I understand how the theory is build from first principles.  If I obtained the swap that I apparently was supposed to obtain, I would then be able to use the number operator and commutator to show that I end up with the same state as I started with.  Given the fact that I am not obtaining the same swap state as the one I should get, I feel I must be missing a concept somewhere, but don't know where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noting that $[\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}, \hat{a}_{1}] = [\hat{a}_{2}, \hat{a}_{1}]  = 0$ then $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1}\hat{a}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}\hat{a}_{1}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}\hat{a}_{2}|110\rangle$ can be written as  $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1}\hat{a}_{1}\hat{a}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}\hat{a}_{2}|110\rangle$. Similarily we can move the $\hat{a}_3$ past $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_2$ and move the $\hat{a}_2$ behind the $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_3$ to obtain

$$\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{1}\hat{a}_{1}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{2}\hat{a}_{2}\hat{a}_{3}\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{3}|110\rangle$$. Using $[\hat{a}_3, \hat{a}^{\dagger}_3]= \mathbb{I}$, this expression can be written in terms of number computation operators

$$N_1 N_2 (\mathbb{I}+ N_3) | 110\rangle$$

where $N_3 |110\rangle = 0$ but the state $|110\rangle$ has eigenvalue 1 for both $N_1 $ and $N_2$ operators hence we yield back our orginal state.

Comment: I see where I confused my understanding.  It is defined  that $\left[\hat{a}_{i},\hat{a}^{\dagger}_{j} \right] = \delta_{ij}$ and I treated this as equal to 1 without recalling that if $i \neq j$ that it is 0.  Foolish mistake!  Thank you for your help!